# How to solve reassignment to val error?

Tags: scala, parsing

I am writing a parser trying to calculate the result of an expression containing float and an RDD, I have override + - / * and it works fine. In one part I am getting the famous error the "reassignment to val" but cannot figure out how to solve it. 
Part of the code is as follow:

```
 def calc: Parser[Any]=rep(term2 ~ operator) ^^ {
  //match a list of term~operator
  case termss =>
    var stack =List[Either[RDD[(Int,Array[Float])], Float]]()
    var lastop:(Either[RDD[(Int,Array[Float])], Float], Either[RDD[(Int,Array[Float])], Float]) => RDD[(Int,Array[Float])] = add
    termss.foreach(t =>
    t match { case nums ~ op => {
                            if (nums=="/path1/test3D.xml")
                                    nums=sv.getInlineArrayRDD()
                            lastop = op; stack = reduce(stack ++ nums, op)}}
    )

   stack.reduceRight((x, y) => lastop(y, x))
}
def term2: Parser[List[Any]] = rep(factor2)
def factor2: Parser[Any] = pathIdent | num | "(" ~> calc <~ ")"
def num: Parser[Float] = floatingPointNumber ^^ (_.toFloat)
```

I defined pathIdent to parse paths.
Here is the error:

```
    [error]  reassignment to val:
    [error]                                         nums=sv.getInlineArrayRDD()
    [error]                                             ^
```

I have changed def in term2, factor2, and num to var although I knew it seems incorrect but that's the only thing came into my mind to test and it didn't work.
Where is it coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this piece of code:

```
case nums ~ op => {
  if (nums=="/path1/test3D.xml")
    nums=sv.getInlineArrayRDD()
```

The `nums` isn't reassignable because it comes from the pattern matching (see the `case` line).  The last line (`nums = ...`) is trying to assign to `nums` when it can't.

Comment: To get around the reassignable problem, you can create a new `val` out of it.  E.g., `val newNums = if (???) ??? else ???`.

Comment: I did it like: var newNums = if(nums=="...") newNums=sv.getInline() else newNumes=0 ....
it gives the following error: recursive variable newNums needs type

Comment: @Rubbic That's because you're trying to define something (`newNums`) and using it at the same time. That should be: `val newNums = if (num == "...") sv.getInline() else 0